# Directing movement toward patchvariable-in-cone - alternative to uphill-patch-variable

Tags: netlogo

I'm having major trouble trying to direct turtle movement toward an amount of patch-variable in-cone 20 45 10, and I think it might be because I am trying to modify uphill-chemical to fit the new reporter. For instance, with the code below, the ants were jumping across the world from one side to another. I just don't know how to clearly direct turtle movement toward the total-chemical-in-cone, as designated by the reporter below, instead of just uphill-chemical of the surrounding eight patches. Is the uphill primitive interfering with my goal, which is to direct movement toward the chemical within the entire cone, and if so, what could I use, since fd 1 is not directing movement properly?

```
to uphill-total-chemical-scent-in-cone
  let scent-ahead total-chemical-scent-in-cone 20 45 10
  let scent-right chemical-scent-at-angle 90
  let scent-left chemical-scent-at-angle -90
  if (scent-right > scent-ahead) or (scent-left > scent-ahead)
  [ ifelse scent-right > scent-left
    [ rt 45 ]
    [ lt 45 ] ]
  if scent-ahead > scent-left or scent-ahead > scent-right
  [fd 1]

to-report total-chemical-scent-in-cone [cone-distance angle angle-width ] ; ant procedure - reports the mean amount of pheromone in cone
  rt 45
  let p patches in-cone 20 10 ;; cone distance 20 patches angle 45 angle width 10
  lt 45
  if p = nobody [ report 0 ]
  ;ask p [ show chemical ]
  report (sum [chemical] of p)
end
```

Comment: It isn't obvious to me that what might be wrong with the code you've provided. I think you have some debugging to do here. _Why_ and _how_, precisely, were your ants "jumping across the world from one side to another"? Adding `print` statements to your code might help investigate, `inspect` is useful too.

Comment: The `p = nobody` part of the code can never be true, since `p` is an agentset, and an agentset, even if empty, is never equal to `nobody`. `nobody` is not an empty agentset, it is a special value used to indicate the absence of a _single_ agent. Regardless, I doubt that's what's causing your code to behave incorrectly.